# How to get a specific index value in array by using map and stream in Kotlin?

Tags: arrays, list, kotlin, arraylist, stream

I want to get a list of `String` in `ArrayList<Array<String>>` by using `stream()` and `map` in Kotlin.

Each `Array<String>` of my `arrayList` has 3 values and I want to get the first index value and the last index value of each array.

This is my code:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val result: List<String>
    val obj1 = arrayOf("fruit", "Mangue", "Africa")
    val obj2 = arrayOf("Milk", "Soja", "Europ")
    val obj3 = arrayOf("Meat", "cochon","Asia")
    val myArrayList: ArrayList<Array<String>> = ArrayList<Array<String>>(3)  
    val myList: MutableList<Array<String>> = mutableListOf<Array<String>>()  
    myList.add(obj1)  
    myList.add(obj2)  
    myList.add(obj3)
    myArrayList.addAll(myList)  
    result = myArrayList.stream().map{it -> ("${it[0]}-${it[2]}")}.toList()
    println("ArrayList of objects  :")
    println(myArrayList)
    println("my list of String result")
    println(result)
}
```

I want to have this list of `String` in my result:

```
[fruit-africa,milk-Europ,Meat-Asia]
```

Also, when I print `myArrayList`, I have a bad result:

```
ArrayList of objects  :
[[Ljava.lang.String;@5caf905d, [Ljava.lang.String;@27716f4, [Ljava.lang.String;@8efb846]
```

How can I do it, please?

Comment: You don't have to use `stream` in Kotlin. Just simply do this: `result = myArrayList.map{it -> "${it[0]}-${it[2]}"}`. You can print `myArrayList` in multiple ways, for example `println(myArrayList.joinToString(", ", "[", "]") { it.joinToString(", ", "[", "]") })`

Comment: Your bad result is because Arrays don’t have a nice `toString()` function like Lists do. You should call `joinToString()` on an Array before printing it.

Comment: Maybe it's worth highlighting once again: **`ArrayList` is not an array; it's an implementation of the `List` interface**. It happens to use an array internally, but that's just an implementation detail. And: **You should prefer lists to arrays.** Lists are much better supported in the standard library, play better with generics, have multiple implementations you can choose between, and usually have nice `toString()` etc. methods. Arrays have a few specific uses (varargs, interoperability with old code, low-level implementation) but for everything else, lists are better.

Answer (score 1):

## Your Question

When I run your code, this is the output I see:

```
ArrayList of objects  :
[[Ljava.lang.String;@5b480cf9, [Ljava.lang.String;@6f496d9f, [Ljava.lang.String;@723279cf]
my list of String result
[fruit-Africa, Milk-Europ, Meat-Asia]
```

And in your question, you have:

> I want to have this list of `String` in my result:
>
> ```
> [fruit-africa,milk-Europ,Meat-Asia]
> ```

So, it looks like you already have the output you want for `result`. The only difference from the actual output is the lack of a space after each comma. If you don't want that space, then use [`joinToString`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/join-to-string.html) to customize the output:

```kotlin
println(result.joinToString(",", "[", "]"))
```

As for:

```
[[Ljava.lang.String;@5b480cf9, [Ljava.lang.String;@6f496d9f, [Ljava.lang.String;@723279cf]
```

You see that output because arrays don't override the `toString()` function, and therefore use the default implementation. In Kotlin, you can use [`contentToString()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/content-to-string.html) to get similar output as you see when printing a `List`.

```kotlin
println(myArrayList.joinToString(", ", "[", "]") { it.contentToString() })
```

So, here is the updated code with the above changes:

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val result: List<String>
    val obj1 = arrayOf("fruit", "Mangue", "Africa")
    val obj2 = arrayOf("Milk", "Soja", "Europ")
    val obj3 = arrayOf("Meat", "cochon","Asia")
    val myArrayList: ArrayList<Array<String>> = ArrayList<Array<String>>(3)
    val myList: MutableList<Array<String>> = mutableListOf<Array<String>>()
    myList.add(obj1)
    myList.add(obj2)
    myList.add(obj3)
    myArrayList.addAll(myList)
    result = myArrayList.stream().map{it -> ("${it[0]}-${it[2]}")}.toList()
    println("ArrayList of objects  :")
    println(myArrayList.joinToString(", ", "[", "]") { it.contentToString() })
    println("my list of String result")
    println(result.joinToString(",", "[", "]"))
}
```

Which gives this output:

```
ArrayList of objects  :
[[fruit, Mangue, Africa], [Milk, Soja, Europ], [Meat, cochon, Asia]]
my list of String result
[fruit-Africa,Milk-Europ,Meat-Asia]
```

---

## Potential Improvements

With all that said, there are a few things you can simplify in your code:

- This is a minor point, but since you don't use the `args` parameter you can actually omit it.
- Your `myList` is not necessary; you can add your arrays directly to `myArrayList`.
- Given the small number of elements in each array, and the small number of arrays, you can actually create the `List<Array<String>>` and populate it with a single [`listOf`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/list-of.html).

  - For variable types, you should prefer using `List`, the interface, rather than `ArrayList`, the implementation. This is known as "programming to an interface". Preferring `List` also means better use of `listOf` and `mutableListOf`, which are the idiomatic ways of creating lists in Kotlin.
- You should prefer using `List` over arrays. In other words, create a `List<List<String>>` instead of a `List<Array<String>>`.

  - Lists do override the `toString()` method, providing readable output. Also, lists have better API support and work better with generics.
- You don't need to use `stream()`. Kotlin provides many extension functions for arrays and `Iterable`s, one of those being [`map`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map.html) which returns a `List`. Yes, these transformation functions are eagerly evaluated, unlike with streams, but given you're only performing one transfomration this doesn't really matter (in fact, the stream is likely less performant).

  - See [kotlin.collections](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/) for the available built-in extension functions.
- Given you want the first and last elements of each array, I would use [`first()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/first.html) and [`last()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/last.html).

Here is the simplified code (I added explicit types to make it clearer what the variables reference):

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val lists: List<List<String>> = listOf(
        listOf("Fruit", "Mangue", "Africa"),
        listOf("Milk",  "Soja",   "Europe"),
        listOf("Meat",  "Cochon", "Asia")
    )
    println("List of lists of strings:")
    println(lists)

    val result: List<String> = lists.map { "${it.first()}-${it.last()}" }
    println("Result:")
    println(result)
}
```

Output:

```
List of Arrays:
[[Fruit, Mangue, Africa], [Milk, Soja, Europe], [Meat, Cochon, Asia]]
Result:
[Fruit-Africa, Milk-Europe, Meat-Asia]
```

Comment: Also you didn't say it explicitly, but it's better to use `List` instead of the specific `ArrayList` implementation. That way you'll get used to using things like `listOf` and you'll avoid requiring the `ArrayList` type for function parameters etc

Comment: Hi @Slaw If i have this situation val arrays: List<Array<String>> = listOf(
        arrayOf("Fruit", "Mangue", "Africa1", "Africa2", "Africa3", "Africa4"),
        arrayOf("Milk",  "Soja",   "Europe1",   "Europe2",   "Europe3",   "Europe4"),
        arrayOf("Meat",  "Cochon", "Asia1", "Asia2", "Asia3", "Asia4", "Asia5")
    ) and  i want to get the first element and the fourth element, how can i do

Comment: @ln3106 You want the first element, so nothing needs to change there. And you want the fourth element, which is not the last element, so you have to change how you get the third/last element so that you now get the fourth element. Based on the code in your question, you already know how to do this.